# My website has css issue on right side of website

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, jquery-mobile

Please visit this url:

> dev.dgconcepts.com.pk

[image]

I don't know why, when we swipe left or right on mobile responsive, the website moves a little bit on both sides.

I don't know what the issue is.

Can someone tell through chrome console check please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

try to add this CSS code to additional CSS in your WordPress control panel.

```
body { width: 105% !important; }
```

tested and worked.

Comment: No sir it couldnt do for me

Comment: do you still need help?